# How do I initiate a function when an Ember JS controller loads?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am new to Ember.js. I'm trying to set the values of dataset:categories and dataset:data:data in this script. The situation is that I followed [this article](http://rohitrox.github.io/2014/03/16/emberjs-and-highcharts/) to insert a Highcharts view into my template but I need to get the data dynamically so I tried to modify the controller to handle this. What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

```
App.InsightsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
setupController: function(controller, model) {
    var chartJSON = []; // Empty in example but I have a valid JSON

    var KPICategories = [],
        KPIValues = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < chartJSON.length; i++) {
        var categoryDate = new Date(chartJSON[i]['file_creation_time']);
        KPICategories.push(categoryDate.getHours() + ':' + categoryDate.getMinutes());
        KPIValues.push(Math.round(chartJSON[i]['kpi_value']));
    };

    console.log(KPICategories);
    controller.set('dataset:categories', KPICategories);
    controller.set('dataset:data:data', KPIValues);
},
dataset: {
    categories: null,
    data: [{
        name: 'Downlink Throuput',
        data: null
    }]
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`setupController` is a route hook. Cut/paste it into the route:

```
App.InsightsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  // This will fire after the model hook callback has returned, allowing you to interact with it.
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    var chartJSON = []; // Empty in example but I have a valid JSON

    var KPICategories = [],
        KPIValues = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < chartJSON.length; i++) {
        var categoryDate = new Date(chartJSON[i]['file_creation_time']);
        KPICategories.push(categoryDate.getHours() + ':' + categoryDate.getMinutes());
        KPIValues.push(Math.round(chartJSON[i]['kpi_value']));
    };

    console.log(KPICategories);
    controller.set('dataset:categories', KPICategories);
    controller.set('dataset:data:data', KPIValues);
  }
});
```

You can fire off any methods in the controller directly from here. For example:

```
App.InsightsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  // This will fire after the model hook callback has returned, allowing you to interact with it.
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    //... You already set up the properties and whatnot...
    controller.fireOffMethod(args);
    controller.set('property_bar', controller.get('foo'));
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried this before but it wouldn't load the chart. I used Handlebars to simply output the array to HTML and it does work. However, charts still don't load. Is it because the chart view is loaded before the above script runs?

Comment: No, the view rendering happens later in the run loop. It's possible that you aren't even firing off the highcharts js? Do you have a view that makes use of `didInsertElement`?

Comment: I do have it. Here's my view: http://www.codesend.com/view/89ae16ce819c2953bda2bee130d64d63/.

Comment: Can you also show me how you are using that view within a template?

Comment: {{ view App.HighChartsView dataset=dataset title="" type="line" yAxisTitle="" }}

Comment: So my guess is you are trying to initialize that view before the model is ready. I would wrap an if statement. `{{#if dataSetHasData}}{{ view App.HighChartsView dataset=dataset title="" type="line" yAxisTitle="" }}{{/if}}` and `dataSetHasData` is a computed property.